# *Urgent* need help to create SharePoint Calculated Column

Tags: custom-list, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have a SharePoint List in which one column has Account numbers like
000000123456
000012345678
C00012345

Now I have to create a calculated Column which can display the above fields as
123456
12345678
C00012345.

Comment: So, are you just looking to truncate the first several digits? Or what?

Answer (score 0):

See: http://www.viewmaster365.com/365coach/#/Calculated_Column_Functions_List

```
=TEXT(VALUE("000000123456"),"0")

=TEXT(VALUE("00000012345678"),"0")
```

returns the value as text (without thousands separator)

```
=VALUE("C00012345")
```

is an error, because its not a value

So the complete formula with a basefield `MyValue`:

```
=IF( ISERROR(VALUE(MyValue))  ,  MyValue  ,  TEXT(VALUE(MyValue),"0") )
```

Comment: I appreciate your help. I am new to this stuff. Can you elaborate on MyValue. =TEXT(VALUE([Account Number]),"0") removes the zero's from Account Number column. 

Do I need to save it as one column (let's say Account Number 1, and then create another Calculated column with
=IF( ISERROR(VALUE([Account Number 1]))  ,  [Account Number 1] ,  TEXT(VALUE([Account Number 1]),"0") )??

Please give the formula exactly.

Comment: Yes, as by your example they remove the leading zeros.  The Formula is exact as you replicate with you own Field. Start learning Formulas with Excel, much easier/faster